# Use a Monitor like a Semaphore?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

When using monitors for most concurrency problems, you can just put the critical section inside a monitor method and then invoke the method. However, there are some multiplexing problems wherein up to n threads can run their critical sections simultaneously. So we can say that it's useful to know how to use a monitor like the following:

```
monitor.enter();
runCriticalSection();
monitor.exit();
```

What can we use inside the monitors so we can go about doing this?

Side question: Are there standard resources tackling this? Most of what I read involve only putting the critical section inside the monitor. For semaphores there is "The Little Book of Semaphores".

Comment: _there are some multiplexing problems wherein up to n threads can run their critical sections simultaneously_ - not clear. A critical section is by definition a piece of code that is executed by one thread at a time only.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin Ah, I get it. I expanded the use of "critical section" to refer to code that can be executed at most n times only. Do you have another term for what I called critical section?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, any solution must satisfy this:

- When fewer than n threads are in the critical section, a thread calling `monitor.enter()` should not block—i.e. the only thing preventing it from progressing should be the whims of the scheduler.
- At most n threads are in the critical section at any point in time; implying that
- When thread n+1 calls `monitor.enter()`, it must block until a thread calls `monitor.exit()`.

As far as I can tell, your requirements are equivalent to this:

- The "monitor" is a semaphore with an initial value of `n`.
- `monitor.enter()` is `semaphore.prolaag()` (aka `P`, `decrement` or `wait`)
- `monitor.exit()` is `semaphore.verhoog()` (aka `V`, `increment` or `signal`)

So here it is, a semaphore implemented from a monitor:

```
monitor Semaphore(n):
    int capacity = n
    method enter:
        while capacity == 0: wait()
        capacity -= 1
    method exit:
        capacity += 1
        signal()
```

Use it like this:

```
shared state:
    monitor = Semaphore(n)

each thread:
    monitor.enter()
    runCriticalSection()
    monitor.exit()
```

**The other path**

I guess that you might want some kind of syntactic wrapper, let's call it Multimonitor, so you can write something like this:

```
Multimonitor(n):
    method critical_section_a:
        <statements>
    method critical_section_b:
        <statements>
```

And your run-time environment would ensure that at most n threads are active inside any of the monitor methods (in your case you just wanted one method).  I know of no such feature in any programming language or runtime environment.

Perhaps in python you can create a `Multimonitor` class containing all the book-keeping variables, then subclass from it and put decorators on all the methods; a metaclass-involving solution might be able to do the decorating for the user.

**The third option**

If you implement monitors using semaphores, you're often using a semaphore as a mutex around monitor entry and resume points.  I think you could initialize such a semaphore with a value larger than one and thereby produce such a Multimonitor, complete with `wait()` and `signal()` on condition variables.  But: it would do more than what you need in your stated question, and if you use semaphores, why not just use them in the basic and straightforward way?